# Should we start a community blog?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-declined

Stack Exchange runs blog services for some sites upon request on their blog site, [Blog Overflow](http://stackexchange.com/blogs). Stack Exchange has a blog post dedicated to [what they're looking for in a blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/), and I think we meet and exceed it on all counts. We have people with fascinating ideas and experience, and who write rather well. We even have a few bloggers on-site who are well-known.

Should we ask for one?

---

Role-playing games are a complex and interesting field. I'm sure most of you have heard of the Forge, and many of the experimental games that came from the Forge - that's just one place we have previously discussed RPG theory.

There are hundreds of broad questions that are impossible to reasonably answer on the site, but which would likely be of fascination to our dear and beloved members. I know we have the capacity for content out there - for those of you who've stayed in chat a while, there's very frequently a discussion about RPG theory or some other RPG-related topic.

In short, I believe we have the capacity to generate interesting content. In order to answer [whether we should have a blog](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/blog-overflow/):

- Who would be willing to contribute?
- Should the scope of the blog be limited from "RPG-related topics"?
- How often should posts be released?

Comment: Old, but related: [Would an RPG Blog get read?](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1096/4398)

Comment: The trouble with starting a blog is that you then have to write in it...

Comment: More seriously, the trouble with running a blog is the audience: the RPG blog community is saturated with general-purpose blogs. Does the blogosphere need another? Will anyone read it? Maybe we do a more site-centric one then? But would anyone read *that*? Do we have expertise or raw material to create a blog with a unique topic rather than general? These look like rhetorical questions, but they're not intended to be—I don't know the answers to them.

Comment: @Seven Good points, and I don't have an answer either. Unless we can think of good answers to your questions, this may have to be put on hold until it would more significantly benefit the RP community as a whole.

Comment: Community Blogs is being entirely discontinued now, so I've made this [status-declined] to resolve the [feature-request] tag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Stack Exchange is no longer starting new community blogs. See [We're no longer starting new individual site Community Blogs - here's why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/244467/were-no-longer-starting-new-individual-site-community-blogs-heres-why) if you want to find out the reasoning behind that.

The situation may change in the future, but for now, we don't need to worry about whether or not to start one up 'cause we can't.

Comment: Further update: I have learned from a Community Manager that they're now discontinuing existing blogs as well.

Comment: @SevenSidedDie Good.  A blog adds noise, and our purpose is better signal to noise ratios.